# Create SQL target tables automatically in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to Data Factory.
I would like to copy data from REST API into SQL Server tables.
Is there a way to automatically create SQL tables with data types based on the API calls? I don't want to do this manually.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi mshparber, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't auto create SQL table with Rest API Source:
[image]

We will get the bellow error:

```
Table option is not applicable when source dataset type is RestResource.
```

It's not supported for now.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! So what is the fastest way to create a target table based on my REST source. I have a lot of columns with different data type - dates, datetime, varchar, int etc....

Comment: @mshparber you could try set a new table name in Sink dataset.